# Send multiple attachments( images and PDFs) to gmail through intent

Tags: android, uri, email-attachments, filechooser

I have a file chooser which provides me with the URI of the selected files( could be multiple or single ), now I want to send those selected files(images and pdfs) to gmail app using intent. I tried everything available online to send attachments with intent but failed to succeed. Please guide me through this this thing, have been stuck here for days.

Asking for runtime permissions using EasyPermissions:

```
if (!EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(AddEventActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
                EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(AddEventActivity.this, "Read External data",2, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }
```

File chooser:

```
Intent chooseFile = new Intent();
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                    chooseFile.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
                }
                else {
                    chooseFile.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                }
                chooseFile.setType("*/*");
                chooseFile.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
                chooseFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                chooseFile = Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Choose a file");
                startActivityForResult(chooseFile, PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
```

Storing the URI returned in a HashMap : uriMap

Gmail Intent

```
Intent emailSelectorIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
            emailSelectorIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
            Log.d("mailList", Arrays.toString(subarray));

            final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, subarray);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,(CharSequence) eventName.getText().toString());
            ArrayList<String> bodyList = new ArrayList<>();
            String body = eventDesc.getText().toString() + " at " + eventVenue.getText().toString() + ", " + hourSelect + ":" + minuteSelect;
            bodyList.add(body);

            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, bodyList);
            emailIntent.setSelector(emailSelectorIntent);
            emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            emailIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
            Iterator iterator = uriMap.entrySet().iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry mapElement = (Map.Entry) iterator.next();
                uris.add((Uri) mapElement.getValue());
            }
            if (uris.size() != 0)
                emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);

            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Choose an email application..."));
```

OnActivityResult code

if multiple files are selected

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.getClipData().getItemCount(); i++) {
                            
Uri uri = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();}
```

else if single file is selected

```
Uri uri;
uri = data.getData();
```

LogCat error

```
2020-08-01 16:56:16.414 30575-30575/? E/Gmail: ComposeActivity:Error adding attachment
gon: SecurityException when openAssetFileDescriptor.
    at goo.a(PG:5)
    at goo.a(PG:45)
    at dvt.a(PG:137)
    at duz.run(PG:2)
    at dvt.a(PG:176)
    at dvt.a(PG:144)
    at dvt.a(PG:443)
    at drq.a(Unknown Source:24)
    at bbkz.a(Unknown Source:19)
    at bdvu.a(Unknown Source:2)
    at bdvw.run(PG:9)
    at bdzb.run(Unknown Source:7)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
    at bbja.run(PG:2)
    at aqsr.run(Unknown Source:18)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

Help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I tried everything available online to send attachments with intent but failed to succeed" -- please edit your question with a [mcve] demonstrating what you tried and explaining, in detail, what "failed to succeed" means.

Comment: @CommonsWare added the code.

Comment: Gmail does not seem to like your `Uri` values. Right now, you are always using `ACTION_GET_CONTENT`, as you overwrite your `Intent` action -- you might try moving that into an `else` for your `if` that sets `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. It is unclear if your `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` code is in the same activity instance as is your `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`/`ACTION_GET_CONTENT` code -- if it is not, fix that. And you could write a scrap app that will respond to your `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` `Intent`, so you can receive what you are sending and check to see if the `Uri` values are usable there.

Comment: @CommonsWare corrected that if/else thing, but problem prevails, to clarify all these codes are in the same activity instance. Moreover, I have used the same URIs( uriMap values ) to upload these files to firebase storage and generate downloadable URI, which seem to work fine. But am clueless for the intent part :(                For more clarification I have added the onActivityResult code of file chooser action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code for file chooser:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("*/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,true);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "ChooseFile"), PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
```

Code for intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, subarray);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.dir/email");
            ArrayList<Uri> uris=new ArrayList<Uri>();
            if (uriMap.size()!=0) {
                Iterator i= uriMap.entrySet().iterator();
                while(i.hasNext()){
                    Map.Entry mapElement = (Map.Entry) i.next();
                    uris.add((Uri)mapElement.getValue());
                }
                intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uris);
            }
            intent.setPackage("com.google.android.gm");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 101);
```

using `intent.setType()` and `intent.setPackage()` worked for me!